# mysql - initialize local variable (in stored procedure) from a query result

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, local-variables

I am trying to create a stored procedure that would perform the select shown as the line before the end. It would take the earliest StartDate and the latest EndDate from my usertable and select all days between from those dates from my reference calendar table. Unfortunately whatever syntax I will try to use I will always get an error message on assigning the values from usertable selects to start/endday variables. I have not found many resources specifying the correct syntax from examples I have seen I tried the following.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE seldays() 

BEGIN 

DECLARE startday DATE;
SET startday = (SELECT MIN(StartDate) from user1table1);
DECLARE endday DATE;
SET endday = (SELECT MAX(EndDate) from user1table1);
SELECT calendar_date FROM calendar WHERE calendar_date >= startday AND calendar_date< endday;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I also tried to assign values thusly

```
SELECT MIN(StartDate) from user1table1 INTO endday;
```

To no avail. I might be able to make the procedure work without storing these variables - but it is something that I will sooner or later need to use anyway.
So how does one fill local variables with query results in Mysql correctly?

Comment: Why not simple `SELECT calendar_date FROM calendar c, (SELECT MIN(StartDate) mindate, MAX(StartDate) maxdate from user1table1) u where c.calendar_date >= u.mindate and c.calendar_date <= u.maxdate)` ? Why a procedure instead of a simple select?

Comment: Declare variable should be on top

Comment: Thank You Ankit Agrawal it was such a simple thing I missed

Answer (score 2):

I would just do this in a single query.  Why bother with variables?

```
SELECT c.calendar_date
FROM calendar c JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(StartDate) as startday, MAX(EndDate) as endday
      FROM user1table1
     ) u
     ON c.calendar_date >= u.startday AND c.calendar_date < u.endday;
```

Comment: Could work - but nevertheless I  guess I might some day need a way to store some query results in local variables and it just doesn't seem to work right now.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment
"Declare variable should be on top" by Ankit Agrawal ..

I can conclude this thing answered. I post this post as a correct answer so If anyone has the same problem they can quickly look.

**DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE seldays() 

BEGIN 

DECLARE startday DATE;
DECLARE endday DATE;
SELECT MIN(StartDate) INTO startday FROM user1table1;
SELECT MAX(EndDate) INTO endday FROM user1table1;
SELECT calendar_date FROM calendar WHERE calendar_date >= startday AND calendar_date< endday;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: can we initialize more than one variable from a single query in this way?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(StartDate) into startday from user1table1
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use the `select ... into <variable list> from ...` [statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) to assign results variables:

```
select min(StartDate) into startday from user1table1;
select max(EndDate) into endday from user1table1;
```

Comment: Hmm tried that still errors. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE endday DATE;

Comment: Your error message is not related to assigning a value to the variables, your entire question is misleading.

Comment: Your 2nd declare should be moved up to the front. All declares must come before any other statement.